# Does this work as a way to initiate background work that I can cancel without caring about the result?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm working on a C# tool to simulate an ongoing workload on a database while a certain sequence of queries/stored procedures runs, in order to gauge the performance of those queries/stored procs. What I'd like to do is kick off a perpetual set of basic `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE` queries on the database, initiate the stored procs whose  performance I'm testing, wait for the stored procs to complete, then cancel the `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE` queries. What I have right now is along the lines of:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
{
    // this inserts work items, triggering the stored procs under test
    await StartItemProcessing();

    var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;

    // async method, called without await
    StartQueries(cancellationToken);

    // this polls the database, checking for completion of the stored procs
    await CheckForProcessingCompletion();

    cancellationSource.Cancel();
}

private static async Task StartQueries(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // run async database queries with SqlClient
        // awaiting the results and passing cancellationToken to the various async method calls
    }
}
```

What I imagine will happen is that when `StartQueries()` is called, the database queries will begin running in the while loop while execution continues through `Main()`. Once `cancellationSource.Cancel()` executes, the queries in progress will be canceled, the `while` loop's condition will change to false, and everything will shut down smoothly. Is this a correct mental model of what will happen? Is this the idiomatic way to do what I'm trying to do in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mostly got it, but you should use a variable to store the `Task` created by calling `StartQueries` and `await` it after calling `Cancel`. This way, you make sure that `StartQueries` finishes as you expect it to.

```
// async method, called without await
var queryTask = StartQueries(cancellationToken);

// this polls the database, checking for completion of the stored procs
await CheckForProcessingCompletion();

cancellationSource.Cancel();
await queryTask;
```

Comment: I tried this, but `await queryTask` threw a `TaskCanceledException`. Should I surround the `await` with a try/catch block, or should I take another approach?

Comment: The `TaskCanceledException` was thrown from within the `StartQueries()` method; if I surround the while loop there with a try/catch, it swallows the exception and returns without issues. Is that an appropriate way to handle cancellation?

Comment: Are you calling `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in `StartQueries`? If you are, you don't *have* to. It's common to design a method like `StartQueries` (loops infinitely, and you expect to cancel it in the standard use case) to use a cancellation token to finish gracefully - that is, simply use `IsCancellationRequested` to stop looping when the token is cancelled and exit successfully. Doing that shouldn't cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I'm not calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`; I think the exception's thrown because the `StartQueries` task is transitioned to the Canceled state. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation), "If you are waiting on a Task that transitions to the Canceled state, a TaskCanceledException exception (wrapped in an AggregateException exception) is thrown".

Comment: Ah, if you are passing the cancellationToken to other async calls inside `StartQueries`, then *those* are likely throwing the exception, and it's bubbling up. So, you will need to handle the `OperationCanceledException` *somewhere* with a try/catch. You could do it inside `StartQueries` or outside of it, it doesn't really matter. Conceptually it probably makes more sense to do it inside, since the design of `StartQueries` is such that you expect to cancel it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!